# Can an Uchiha master Sage Mode?

Tags: naruto

If a child whose father is Uchiha and mother is Senju is born, will this child awaken the Rinnegan?
Will they be able to use Sage Mode because Senju have strong chakra to harness Sage Mode?

[image]

Comment: Is your question about sage mode or activation of rinnegan?

Comment: Please edit your question. The question title is asking something totally different from what the body is asking. Related to title question: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20851/why-did-the-uchihas-never-try-to-learn-sage-mode Related to question in body: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20464/does-the-uchihasenju-dna-ratio-matter-in-awakening-the-rinnegan

Comment: This is 2 questions wrapped into 1.

Comment: The uchiha and Senju are not what is required for awakening the rinnegan what awakens the rinnegan in the situation your speaking of is the chakra of indra and ashura Wich happens to be the Senju and uchiha in the case of Madara and Hashirama but this is not always the case in the way that Naruto an Uzumaki was the iteration from his generation of ashura what makes a rinnegan is the mixing of the two chakras not the two respective clans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well.. In order to awaken the Rinnegan, you need to have Ashura's and Indra's chakra. Having Uchiha and Senju DNA won't necessarily activate the Rinnegan unless those Uchiha and Senju are reincarnated Ashura and Indra.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with an Uchiha learning Senin mode is that for you to learn that you need a large amount of chakra reserves. Something that the Uchihas tend to have a problem with.

You can see a lot of Itachi's early fights, Kisame mentions that Itachi cannot use his eyes for a large amount of time as it puts a large burden on his limited chakra reserves.

Also you need an immense amount of chakra control as to not let the nature energy turn you into a frog. Even Jiraiya, one of the legendary three, could not completely control the nature energy.

He admitted that he could never use his sennin powers without acquiring some frog features.

Naruto on the other hand, with his Uzumaki heritage, a clan that has worn at least twice the title of Nine Tails' jinchuuriki, and the fact that he had a truly immense amount of chakra in him from birth, made him able to control large amounts of chakra unlike any of the other sennin users.

Comment: Neil Meyer!  You and I have a **lot** in common - have music degree, like anime, and are also interested in Christianity and philosophies, and so much more!

Answer (score 0):

I believe if a child is born from uchiha father and senju mother, and if that child awakens his sharingan and pushes through physical training(enhance his body strength), then ultimately they WILL awaken the rinnegan()under the proper circumstances -> situations that call to their emotions. The re-incarnation of indra and ashura has little to do with awakening a rinnegan as Indra himself did not awaken the rinnegan even though he was the first son of hagoromo. Madara(Uchiha) awakened his rinnegan only bc he had access to Hashirama DNA(Senju). Same as that uchiha/senju child we talking about here.

Answer (score 0):

Indra and Ashura are the two sons of Hagoromo (sage of six paths) who wielded the rinnegan. As the two sons of Hagoromo were born they each had a half of his chakra. With one half of the chakra they were very strong but they could not awaken the rinnegan on their own, they needed both halves of the chakra to do so. They could do this by transplanting one another's flesh, as demonstrated by Madara Uchiha (Indra's incarnate), thus combining their chakra to make up Hagoromo's chakra, or they could just receive chakra directly from Hagoromo himself as demonstrated by Sasuke Uchiha (Indra's second incarnate), but it is unknown to why Naruto (Ashura's second incarnate) did not receive the rinnegan, (probably because Sasuke already had it or because he already had his own dojutsu, the sage mode eyes).

I mean... If the Uchiha knew it was this easy, they would've seduced some Senju ladies like Tsuna and had rinnegan wielding babies a long time ago, LOL.

Answer (score 0):

For rinnegan you'll basically need the Chakras of the *Reincarnated* Ashura and Indra's.
Not all Uchiha have the reincarnated Indra's Chakra similarity not all Senju's have Ashura's chakra.
This also applies for other clans.